# Android Emulators not Working after Updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

I normally use Android Studio and after updating from 2.2.3 to 2.3 my emulators are no longer working. It's also difficult since Google decided to deprecated the Standalone SDK Manager:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=235625

I found that I can check/select "Show Package Details" but still I had no luck making my Google Android Emulators to work. They seem to run fine, but I can't see the emulators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happened to me too. Seems that there's a package called Intel HAXM no properly installed when you do this upgrade. Try this workaround:

1. Go to the Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager
2. Tap on SDK Tools and uncheck "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)"
3. After uninstall HAXM, install it again
4. Restart Android Studio
5. A new update will appear called "Android Emulators". Just install it and restart Android Studio again.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my issue. I didn't have the Android Emulators prompt but I was able to open the emulators after re-installing Intel HAXM.

Comment: There does #5 appear again?

Answer (score 0):

Check if adb hangs or if multiple adb servers are running

```
cd /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
adb start-server
ps -ef | grep adb

  501  3462 ... /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
  501  3468 ... /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
  501  3483 ... /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
  501  3496 ... /Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
```

If so, killall and restart emulator

```
killall -9 adb
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountering this problem every time I update android studio version.
Can't run app and can't even see the AVD picker.
The problem accurs probably because the project files and the SDK files aren't on the same root directory. I changed the directory when first installed the android studio and made a different directory for the projects .
In other words try finding the original "android-sdk" directory on your computer(prior to update) and copy the path.
After copy go to android studio->Tools->SDK Manager
On the Android SDK Location address bar paste the path of your android sdk location.

Answer (score 0):

For upgrading from 4.1 to ArcticFox, I found the answer in these two threads:

[emulator process terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

[cannot find vulkan-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed)

Answer (score -1):

**Restarting** my Computer, worked for me