# Android Studio Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

When I run the emulator from Android Studio in Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, then it shows the below error:

```
13-01-2021
10:42 AM    Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

10:42 AM    Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

10:42 AM    Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

10:42 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

And the emulator is not opening. I've uninstalled the current version (4.1.1) and installed 4.0.1 of Android Studio, but problem is not solved. Now I'm in the latest version of Android Studio i.e., 4.1.1.

Here is output of `flutter doctor`:

[image: Flutter doctor output Image]

Comment: Check previous solution on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391908/android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-on-windows-7/58392200 . In a nutshell you should try to change graphic settings for your emulator.

Comment: when I creating new emulator with android 11 then graphics option is set to automatic and not changeable. But when I created with android 6 then graphics option is changeable and when I changed to Software - GLES 2.0 then Emulator is Working.

Comment: You can manually change graphics type for the emulator. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152237/android-studio-emulator-vk-version-1-1-check-failed/59715169#59715169

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it breaks multiple rules. It includes a link to 'the solution' edited in later, without any explanation. OP could have written an answer instead of editing the question, but even then a link-only answer would have been violating the guidelines.

Comment: 100% working answer https://professnow.com/blog/solved-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed/

Answer (score 33):

I don't know whether Microsoft [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (VS Code) itself needs `vulkan-1.dll` or any of my following Visual Studio Code extensions,

[image]

as I found out that you may find the missing `vulkan-1.dll` at Visual Studio Code's following folder path:

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\
```

So, if you have Microsoft Visual Studio Code installed, you *may* find the `vulkan-1.dll` at the above-quoted path. From here, just copy the `vulkan-1.dll` file, and paste that in folder:

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64\
```

After pasting the file, restart Android Studio and rerun the emulator/AVD.

Answer (score 26):

I have had this problem since update v30.7.5.

I tried this solution:

1. Create the file ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (for Windows users path should be C:\Users<username>.android\advancedFeatures.ini) with the following content:

   Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator. Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

   ```
   Vulkan = off

   GLDirectMem = on
   ```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is perfect. But what did you mean by "Now it has been resolved."? Are there any updates released after v30.7.5? I couldn't see any.

Comment: My Pixel4/API 30 AVD emulator *USED* to work ... until I recently updated to Android Studio 4.2.2, and updated the SDK tools.  I tried EVERYTHING ELSE on this page, but creating `.android\advancedFeatures.ini` was the only thing that actually worked for me.  Thank you!!!!  PS: "emulator -version" => `30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168)`

Comment: Note that you need to create `advancedFeatures.ini`, not `advancedFeatures.ini.txt` so you must use text and source code editor software like Notepad++ for example, and then save as ini

Comment: Thanks mate! I was struggling with this for so long.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error yesterday, when I installed the latest version of Android Studio (4.2.2 on the stable channel). Every time I tried to start an Emulator I got a warning saying that "The emulator process for AVD was killed", after looking the IDE's Log, I found this:

```
2021-07-01 18:00:48,415 [  62545]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
2021-07-01 18:00:48,415 [  62545]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
2021-07-01 18:00:48,668 [  62798]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.5.0 (build_id 7491168) (CL:N/A)
2021-07-01 18:00:48,676 [  62806]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2021-07-01 18:00:48,676 [  62806]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741819
```

I tried every "solution" I could find but nothing worked until I downloaded vulkan-1.dll and placed it in C:\Windows\System32

Just go to Google and search for vulkan-1.dll file, download it and place it in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: I faced this same issue after updating my android studio to 4.2.2. And now following your instructions but it is still throwing the same error.
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

Comment: I downloaded the file and pasted it in C:\Windows\System32 as mentioned. The file name is vulkan-1.dll and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 9):

[Armando's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed/68227961#68227961) is a solution that works. But I don't feel comfortable packing arbitrary DLL files from the Internet into the *System32* folder.

However, based on Armando's solution, I have found a way in which I feel more comfortable - however, it remains a workaround:

1. The "vulkan-1.dll" can be found for example in the software "draw.io" (64 bit). The DLL is available in the installation folder.
2. Copy the DLL into `{ANDROID_HOME}\emulator\lib64\`
3. Start Android Studio and try out the [AVD](https://source.android.com/setup/create/avd)

Comment: Whatsapp for windows also provides vulcan-1.dll

Answer (score 6):

Error:

1. Go to Help -> Show Log in Explorer.
2. Open idea.log file.
3. Go to the bottom of the file.
4. Found: "`Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed`"

Solution:

1. Download `vulkan-1.dll` from [this](https://www.dll-files.com/vulkan-1.dll.html).
2. Extract and rename dll file names to `vulkan-1.dll`.
3. Paste it in `C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: That's fixed my issue, thank you very much (I've spent the whole evening trying fix it)!! Special thanks for vulkan-1.dll link.
(Btw, changing graphic to shoftware, as was mentioned in other posts helped to fix issue for older Phones in simulator, but Pixel4a, for ex, started working only after adding of vulkan-1.dll).

Comment: Download and use a DLL file from some random place on the Internet? How can this file be trusted?

Answer (score 5):

Four steps.

1. Download the vulkan DLL file from the Internet or get it from any comfortable source.
2. Extract the DLL file
3. Place it in c\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\lib64.
4. Then rename the file to 'vulkan-1.dll'

Then run your emulator and see it come up.

Comment: I faced this same issue after updating my android studio to 4.2.2. And now following your instructions but it is still throwing the same error. 
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed

Answer (score 4):

For me, the solution was as described in [this Microsoft forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/465493/android-emulator-vulkan-1dll-not-found.html).

Create a file under your *.android* directory called *advancedFeatures.ini* and add these two variables:

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

More information on Vulkan support for Windows and Linux can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#29.0.6-vulkan).

Comment: This worked for me on Mac. I had to restart Android studio (and the React Native app too)

Comment: works for me in macbookpro M1

Answer (score 3):

look for vulkan runtime installer instead of copying vulkan-1.dll in system32

[vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home)

[installer (1Mb)](https://sdk.lunarg.com/sdk/download/1.2.198.0/windows/VulkanRT-1.2.198.0-Installer.exe)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running *xamarin.android* in Visual Studio, I strongly recommend uninstall all device simulators and restart Visual Studio and then running your app again.

Comment: What is *"xamarin.android"*?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem where emulator.exe ended abruptly with the same lines on the console. After hours of experiment, downgrading the emulator version from  Android Emulator 3.7.5  to  30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) worked.

I don't think this should be the error vulkan-1.dll is the reason for the process to end abruptly. I am saying this because my logs from a successful run on 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) also showing this dll missing error but continued and the emulator showed up successfully.

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
emulator: WARNING: Your GPU drivers may have a bug. If you experience graphical issues, please consider switching to software rendering.
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
e:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:301: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"

emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
```

FYI. I am running an emulator in a nested VM on the [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V) platform and my GPU version is:

```
android_startOpenglesRenderer: gpu info

GPU #1
  Make: 1414
  Model: Microsoft Basic Render Driver
  Device ID: 008c
```

Comment: Hey @peter-mortensen - I'm also trying to run the emulator in a nested VM on the Hyper-V platform and I am also struggling. One notable thing about downloading old emulator versions is that it requires a specific dl.google.com URL, for example (but not the version you mention):  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6855416.zip - do you have a link for a version that is working for you now?

Answer (score 0):

With the following Android SDK and Tooling:

[SDk Tools Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3HgQ.png)

[SDK Platforms Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIr94.png)

[SDK Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpTjF.png)

I have the above directory structure for the SDK and I have a folder for the vulkan drivers as you can see above. I was able to copy the file: vk_swiftshader.dll to the parent lib64 directory, rename it to vulkan-1.dll to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happened after I installed Visual Studio Code. And the error log is
`WARN - Emulator: Pixel 4 API 30 - Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan`,
So I've just updated the emulator **Graphics** setting to *Software*: [image]

Answer (score -2):

Downgrade the emulator android API version, I was using at API 30 I downgraded it to API28 and emulator starts working

Comment: *How* is that going to be achieved?