# Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf AND Emulator: added library vulkan-1.dll

Tags: android-studio

I was using normally my Android Studio when suddenly it stopped working. the Emulator doesn't work anymore and I don't know what to do. the device show 03 different messages which are:

> Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf  Emulator:
> added library vulkan-1.dll waiting for target device to come online (
> while it is running the screen stay black and doesn't work)

[image]

My information:

- PC Windows 10
- Pixel  API 28

Answer (score 3):

Similar thing happened to me. I followed this therd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed)

I simply had to change the **config.ini** file for the particular emulator I created which is found under `C:/Users/<userName>/.android/avd/<avdName>/config.ini`
and I changed `hw.gpu.mode=auto` to `hw.gpu.mode=off` and got the emulator to start working.

There may be some perfomance issue, but haven't looked into it in depth.

Comment: I have tried so so many steps, nothing worked except this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Hyper-V acceleration in this > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows
worked for me