# Flutter/Android Studio : I get "No connected devices found" although i have created a AVD device

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I've played with the AVD Manager by deleting and adding devices and finally i get the error below. Something that did not do it before...
[image: No connected devices found]

Comment: Have you installed Dart and Flutter plugins and also set up Flutter path in android studio?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed)

Comment: By adding Vulcan-1.dll didn't solve my problem and i got Gradle error "Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug". I reinstall android studio i deleted pubspeck.lock file from my project (i found it from someone else searching  for the Gradle error) and i did pub get from  pubspeck.yaml. Eventually it worked maybe the step of reinstalling Android studio could by steped over.