# Flutter emulator not connecting

Tags: flutter

> "C:\Users\AS\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator" -avd Pixel_API_30 WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature

I tried everything but not working

Comment: can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed