# Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-studio-4.1, android-studio-4.2

After updating to Android Studio 2020.3.1 canary 15, when I try to run an emulator, it gets killed with this error:

> The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_30 has terminated.

It was working correctly in the previous version (4.1.3), but now after installing the new one, it shows the same error.

---

I've tried some solutions had suggested in almost similar cases; however, It still doesn't work.

1. I deleted my emulator (also I cleared inside of directory: /.android/avd/) and created a new one again
2. I updated the HAXM installer to version 7.6.5
3. I tried to run an emulator with lower APIs but...

---

Image of the error:

[image: image of the error]

Comment: Can you also add what OS you are using? I have just tried it on MacOS Big Sur 11.3 and it worked. Maybe "Invalidate Caches / Restart" would help.

Comment: Not having enough disk space could give the same error message. Best way to find the correct cause is to look into log file at "C:\Users\<MyUserName>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log"

Comment: Also, if you just installed Android SDK Studio, rebooting your machine might help, this fixed the issue for me ^^'

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17024538/how-do-i-fix-failed-to-sync-vcpu-reg-error

Comment: My C drive did not have free space to run the emulator
I freed up some space on the C drive

Comment: Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2: the only solution in my case is sign out Windows profile and then go back. I hate this

Comment: Please check if you have Windows Media Pack installed, this is required to run emulator, it's not documented and not may users notice, I have Windows 11 Enterprise N which is the N variant that does come without Media Pack and emulator didn't work until I installed it.

Apps > Optional Features > Add feature > Windows Media Pack

Comment: Why is this issue so frequently asked and hard to resolve? Is there a proper investigating approach to this issue? The idea.log files seem to have only warnings when this problem happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue of latest Emulator.

I upgraded to v30.6.4 last night and got the same issue.

Please use Genymotion instead before Android Studio Emulator issuing its next update.

It's free for personal use.

https://www.genymotion.com/download/

[image]

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy can you explain how to downgrade emulator version?

Comment: @basilkot find a download link of an older version and then replace android_sdk/emulator folder with the downloaded one.

Comment: I can't find download link of an older version of emulator , I updated to latest which does not work , Can you please provide me with a download link of an older version of emualator ?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... so it's half a year and the main core feature of android studio doesn't work without any official fix? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 418):

The main root cause of that issue is lack of free space on your disk

Comment: Do you know how much space do you need to run the emulator? I have 7 GB Free Space and it doesn't work

Comment: It depends on emulator type. Several are below from my setup (x86_64): 

Pixel_5_API_31 - 3.6GB, 
Nexus_7_API_28  - 2.4GB, 
Nexus_4_API_22 - 5.5GB, 
Nexus_5X_API_26 - 5.2GB, 
Nexus_5X_API_28 - 2.7GB, 
Pixel_API_21 - 5.6GB

Comment: @MauroStancato Failed to work with 1.2GB, worked with 6GB, took 100 MB of space on running. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AnsalAli Lack of space is a main root cause but not the only one. Probably you have faced other root cause

Comment: right answer, something had taken almost all of the device internal storage. Recreated a new device with higher internal storage memory solved it, obviously depends on the actual available disk storage your computer has

Comment: I have more than 20 GB of free space. Still, it is not working.

Comment: Thank you so much. In the Device Manager, I had specified 256 GB space thinking that is what my oneplus phone has. But the space is for the emulator to use. So, even 2GB is more than enough.

Comment: lol I just noticed that I have 100MB empty space

Comment: Size is not the issue. I have 32GB Free space. Wrong answer

Comment: @Nik This is the correct answer. Please read it more accurately. The "main root cause" means most likely you affected by that root cause. Less likely with other reasons

Comment: I was able to retrieve GBs of free space after deleting the unused Emulators.

Comment: How do you know my computer so well? :) This was it.

Comment: that's a bolt assumption based on nothing since the error does not show anything else

Comment: The problem with the how much you assigned the internal storage and how much you actually have on the disk so make internal storage then problem will resolved

Comment: This has solved my problem. For me this has to be the correct answer

Comment: I have 6.95TB of free disk space and still have this error.

Comment: I downvoted because even if I still have 700+ gb left, I still encounter this error. The answer is formatted in a away that is very disingenuous as it appears it shifts the blame to the user devices.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, I had this error with 7+ GB free, it went away after I freed up more space up to 15+ GB. It did mention on the [official install page](https://developer.android.com/studio/install) that about 16GB of free space is needed, I guess I overlooked that information.

Comment: @NeonWarge Please read the answer more accurately before your blood completely boiled out. The "main root cause" means most likely you affected by that root cause. Less likely you affected with other reasons. Probably thisi is the correct answer and 300+ upvoters confirmed it.

Comment: I was extremely sceptical but it did work immediately. I had to free up a bit more than 10GB to make it working on a Mac. Thanks a lot @AnatoliiShuba you saved me hours of no sensical debugging !!!

Comment: Well. Thanks!!!
Please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: 8.8 GB free space failed, 10.8 GB free space worked. It is one of the worst error messages (and Google has no excuse of working with software providing no clear error - as they are responsible also for emulator!)

Has anyone already tried to report to google as bug report? (I know that it will be almost certainly ignored)

Comment: @MwBakker  this is based on experience. So far, in my case, every single time I run into it - it was caused by free space requirements. And yes, this message is absurdly not clear and in rare cases may be caused by something else.

Answer (score 134):

Faced this issue after update to arctic fox.

After seeing error message about termination, open android studio logs

On Windows:

`("C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log")`

Or on all platforms:

- Open `Help` Menu
- Select `Open Log in Files/Explorer/...`

scroll it down and try to find log line with text "Emulator terminated with exit code". Probably, the reason for termination can be found a few lines above this message - for me it was

`"Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed".`

If you have the same reason - go to `C:\Windows\System32` directory, search here for file called `vulkan-1-999-0-0-0.dll` and just rename it to `vulkan-1.dll` (i've made a copy just in case and named it "vulkan-1.dll").

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I did not have the same issue but the look into the logs lead me to my solution so +1. For anyone interested mine issue was "Emulator: unknown option: -qt-hide-window" so I ran the command without it.

Comment: I was missing this file vulkan-1-999-0-0-0.dll . I downloaded it from the web. And copied the file with this name to System32 and also renamed its second copy to vulkan-1.dll and copied it to the same folder. It helped

Comment: After the several hours of trying other possible solutions, only this was worked for me. A closer explanation of the issue and link for DLL download is mentioned on the following topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed

Comment: i got the dll from https://www.dll-files.com/vulkan-1.dll.html hope this helps

Comment: I was missing amdvlk64.dll and also vulkan-1.dll. Got amdvlk64.dll from internet and copied twice to System32 as vulkan-1.dll and amdvlk64.dll and it is okay now. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have the vulkan-1.dll file, but adding the advancedFeatures.ini file helped: 
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416846/10749567

Comment: I wonder why would the `vulkan-1.dll` be missing in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory

Comment: The best solution is to completely skip the use of 'vulkan-1.dll' by adding the advancedFeatures.ini file with: Vulkan=off, GLDirectMem=on | https://stackoverflow.com/a/68344341/11211041 
Then you don't have to download an unknown dll-file...

Comment: Not vulkan for me (`"Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 6123 MB at C:\...., need 7372 MB. "`), but big +1 for how to discover what's wrong!

Comment: Upvoting this for the path to the log file which lead to another error message that helped me find the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987153/android-studio-flutter-warning-another-emulator-is-still-running-windows-10. Although, renaming a DLL file seems dangerous.

Comment: @TheLibrarian could you please share how to configure **Android Studio** to remove the `-qt-hide-window` param when starting the emulator from the IDE?

Comment: Following this suggestion, I just removed (moved to be safe) all those vulkan dll's. This solved it. Judging by the firewall message that I got afterwards when starting avd, it (or something) was probably automatically downloaded to some other location.

Comment: Same as TheLibrian, looking at the log leads to solving the problem.  In my case, I either log into my machines local account or onto a domain associated account.  I had my SDK path set to "C:/users/{local machine account}/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk"  This doesn't work when I logged on to my domain associated account.  Solved problem by moving SDK path to "C:/Android/Sdk".   The log info made it clear what was happening. The SDK images weren't where I had access to them!!

Comment: for Flatpak-based installations, the log file path is `~/.var/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/cache/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1/log/idea.log`

Answer (score 121):

Follow below steps to solve the issue:

1. Go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager**
   [image: SDK Tools]
2. In SDK Manager Go To **SDK Tools** Tab and untick the **Android Emulator** and click on Apply. This step will uninstall the Android Emulator.
   [image: Uninstalling Android Emulator]

3. After uninstallation completes:
   Again Open **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** -> **SDK Tools** -> **Install the Android Emulator by enabling the check or tick on Android Emulator**. This step will install the Android Emulator again.
4. After successful installation. Restart Android Studio. Create new emulator device and Run it. This should work.

Comment: This method works well, but if you want to avoid reinstalling the Android Emulator, just update it and that will work. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I just updated the Emulator API to the newest version.

Comment: It worked only once for me.
The second time it again failed as described in the question.
I will try the 'Wipe Data' method instead, and see if that helps …

Comment: already installed, but same issue occurred on 33, below 33 working properly.

Comment: This also helped with "Emulator: unknown option: -qt-hide-window" by installing a newer emulator version, e.g. 33.1.24.0, which knows the option.

Answer (score 75):

Try to kill the emulator process and then you can reboot the emulator.

On Windows, bring out Task Manager and find the emulator process (you can find it starts with qemu-xxx, it might be wrapped inside Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA category), then click end task to kill the process.

[image]

Comment: This did it for me, I think I failed to gracefully terminate the previous emulator and the qemu-xxx process didn't stop

Comment: Finally, It worked for me after trying everything like restarting Android Studio and Cold boot emulator etc.

Comment: This fixed the problem after forgetting to close the emulator before Android Studio

Answer (score 53):

**For Linux (should be similar for windows)**

---

- Locate your Sdk/emulator directory
- Run ./emulator -list-avds
- Note the AVD name form output eg. 'Pixel_2_API_30'
- Run ./emulator @Pixel_2_API_30

This will try to launch the emulator with selected device and show errors if any, in my case it was a disk space issue since I was low on home space.

```
emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata partition. Available: 5084.121094 MB at /home/user/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_30.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.
```

I had plenty of space in other partition/disk, so I changed the AVD location by setting environment variable 'ANDROID_AVD_HOME' to preferred location, post this started the Android Studio and using the AVD Manager recreated a Device, HTH.

Comment: This solution works for me to check how much space was I needing https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#:~:text=The%20AVD%20data%20directory%2C%20also,android%2Favd%2F%20name%20.

Comment: ERROR: process is translated under Rosetta. Attempting to replace emulator installation

Comment: Thanks! KVM was blocked my VirtualBox running in my case: `ioctl(KVM_CREATE_VM) failed: 16 Device or resource busy` `qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize KVM: Device or resource busy
`

Answer (score 36):

After going through all answers.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622341/2986279) can help you finding the root cause. clear the below file and restart the device to know the problem

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log"
```

My problem came as

```
2021-10-13 19:11:54,776 [1564693]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString! arbFound 0 listarbNull/empty 1 0 extFound 0 extNull/empty 1 0 remote 0
```

On further search i found the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41120289/2986279) which points out changing advanced settings (**Ram size**) and **Graphics** configuration

Step 1 :- while setting up device click on advanced settings

[image]

Step 2 :- Change the 2 setting as highlighted. make it 512 and Automatic to Software GLES

[image]

Comment: To find the location of your logs on the Mac, go to Help -> Show Log in Finder

Comment: Perfect Answer! :) after searching and trying a multiple suggestions, only this suggestion works for me. Thank You.

Comment: This works great for emulators that don't have the google play store icons, what about those that do?

Comment: This worked when I selected Graphics as Software. Thanks dude

Comment: Also works with 1024 MB. However, now I have the "System UI isn't responding" error.

Comment: perfect !! it working

Answer (score 19):

This solved the same issue for me:

1. Open text editor (eg. notepad)
2. Type this code:

```
Vulkan=off
GLDirectMem=on
```

3. Save the file as "advancedFeatures.ini" in `.android` directory. If your user is named Admin, under windows it would be: `C:\Users\Admin\.android\advancedFeatures.ini`.
4. Run your app.

Comment: Where can I find this directory on MacOS 12.0.1 (Monterey)?

Comment: /Users/user/.android, if this file is not available simply create a text file called advancedFeatures.ini and add above mentioned code save it in /Users/user/.android folder(this folder is hidden)

Answer (score 12):

This error also occurs when there is `not enough free space` left on your computer.
be sure to free up some more space.

```bash
$ emulator -avd phone2

ERROR   | Not enough disk space to run AVD 'phone2'. Exiting...
```

Comment: have ran `emulator -avd Pixel_API_30_2` and it dropped  error something related to image and `Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine.` . Anyway this answer headed to right way

Answer (score 10):

In Windows, open the Task Manager and kill the process "qemu-system"

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same issue. Fixed it by enabling the Hyper-V on my Windows 10 OS. I just typed Hyper in the Start menu and went to Turn Windows features on or off menu and ticked all the Hyper-V checkboxes like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, enabling Hyper-V on my Windows 10 64-bit system stopped the "The emulator process for AVD" ... "has terminated" crashes for me too! I'm baffled, because instructions at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration indicate the exact opposite, namely that one should disable Hyper-V instead of enabling it. I had also tried HAXM v7.7.0 from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases instead of the HAXM v7.6.5 that was in my <SDK>\C:\Android\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager folder, but that did not work either, only enabling Hyper-V worked thus far.

Comment: checkin both Hyper-V options, worked for me thanks

Answer (score 8):

I updated and had the same problem.
I solved the problem by changing the Multicore CPU and memory

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 8):

*To solve these type of issue, generally you haven't some file, that you need to download it from google and paste. I was facing the same issue. but after a lot of time spent on google finally I have got the solution.*

**Following are the steps:-**

1. Create virtual device using AVD Manager
2. start the emulator
3. if it is showing **your emulator has terminated**
4. Then go to *("C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log")*
5. check the issue by scroll down(on bottom you can check)
6. If you are getting the same issue [image: Check Emulator Error]
7. Then go to ***C:\Windows\System32 directory***, search here for file called vulkan-1-999-0-0-0.dll
8. If file is already in directory, then just rename the file into "vulkan-1.dll"
9. else [download the file from this link](https://www.dll-files.com/download/dd77ed1733723e46d8b4ad541c086c6d/vulkan-1.dll.html?c=OWJ6Z1h3ZW94WVZKQnV4QUFzeTVKdz09)
10. you will have zip file, just extract and paste the vulkan-1-999-0-0-0.dll file and perform the step 8.

Answer (score 7):

This might sound like a joke but restart the computer maybe? I had some emulator processes hanging in the task manager. Restarted the computer and it worked. Maybe it is an android studio bug.

Comment: Worked for me. Restarted Android Studio several times, but still no solution. Restarted the computer and DONE!

Comment: If you have VirtualBox or some other VM software you may discover you cannot run Android Emulator at the same time.  I think mine was hung up and hadn't stopped, so reboot did the trick.  

Answer (score 6):

I would like to mention something about this,

The mentioned solutions works, however, if none works then please make sure you have sufficient space where AVDs are generated.

If system do not find the enough space to operate, it will give this error too, same as in my case.

If space is not an issue for you then mentioned other solutions must work.

Comment: One last thing... Take a look at the Event Log if the Issue is related with Vulkan download and install the Vulkan Runtime:
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/

Comment: after decreasing internal storage space emulator launched.

Answer (score 6):

Check if your disk space of computer is full or not. In my case C:// was full

Answer (score 5):

OK I fixed my problem like the one above by:

I removed the emulator in the AVD manager and reinstalled it. I also deleted the ANDROID_HOME environment variable and it worked again for me in Artic Fox

I am on the latest version of Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch One on Windows 10 and I upgraded the emulator yesterday 8/18/21 and it completely broke functioning emulators.

Answer (score 5):

Was facing similar issue while launching arm64 emulator. I had enough disk space and tried uninstalling the emulator and reinstalling it. But this didn't help.

I was able to figure out the issue by running the below commands:

```
emulator -list-avds
emulator @NameOfAvd
```

This assumes you've `emulator` on the path. Executing the last command showed me the below errors which weren't visible when running from Android Studio:

```
[4453299712]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '/Users/username/../emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64': No such file or directory
```

Executing the command `emulator @NameOfAvd` from the `Android/sdk/tools` path allowed me to start the arm64 AVD.

Comment: This helped. This is Android Studio bug imo. I have my Android SDK location set up as `C:\SDKs\android-studio-canary\SDK\ ` , so running `emulator -avd my_image` should run my image from `C:\SDKs\android-studio-canary\SDK\system-images\android-29\..`, but terminal says `C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\android-automotive-playstore\x86\ is not a valid directory.` So it is simply using a wrong directory here. Maybe it's because I'm using both normal AND canary version of Android Studio.

Comment: It is because the paths for AVD's are generated from system variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. Currently mine is the non-canary version `C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, hence why it shows up on the terminal as an active path. Changing it out with canary sdk path worked!

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution was to **free up some space from the hard-disk**
In my case, only 2gb space was available in the hard-disk.
I made some space by emptying the bin, and now available space was 22gb.

Then I just started the emulator normally ( didn't uninstall or deleted anything) and it started.

Comment: In my case, try Cold Boot Now after free up

Answer (score 4):

In my MacbookPro M1 Pro, The issue was I had selected the x86 image while creating the emulator device.

Changing this setting and using the image from the recommended images resolved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

In case if anyone facing this issue. I solved it by:

- Go to *C:\Users\YourUserName\.android*
- Create a file named advancedFeatures.ini
- Then add the following lines of code in the file:

  ```
   Vulkan = off
   GLDirectMem = on
  ```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to  Device Manager on Android Studio
2. Click Drop Menu on Action Panel
3. Click Wipe Data
4. Launch your AVD Manager Again OR Restart Your computer

Comment: this method works, but it wipe data and it is not the best

Answer (score 3):

I Remove the Emulator folder from the SDK path and download the new component. It's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

My issue is resolved when I changed the **CPU/ABI** setting from "**armeabi-v7a**" to "**x86_64**".

[image]

Comment: Aren't arm emulators slower than x86_64? (it kind of sort of says so when you select arm while creating virtual device). I use MacBook Pro 2021, M1 Pro

Answer (score 3):

For those who running **flutter/Dart** in android studio. Here are the step on how I solved this:

1. Go to any of your current device in Device manager.
2. Click the edit icon (Pen Icon). Then dialog for edit will open.
3. Now change the "Graphics" property in the AVD under Emulated Performance from automatic to "Software-GLES 2.0". it works for me.

**Note: Am using android studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 patch 2**

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to start API_30 devices.

I had to install the latest hardware accelerator version (HAXM v7.7.0) from https://github.com/intel/haxm

Then

Comment: Fingers crossed, but upgrading to the latest HAXM v7.7.0 seemed to be the trick for me.  So far so good.  AVD crashed again the first load but now is loading on the fresh boot.

Answer (score 2):

I face same kind of issues... After increase free space of machine its working fine...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i solved it by delete existing AVD and create new one.

Comment: As easy as this. In my case, I created the device and I couldn't complete the configuration because virtualization in the BIOS wasn't enabled. I enabled it and I continued the configuration of the device. I guess that's why I was getting the error. Removing it and creating it again solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be due to some corrupted data during saving the state. Cold start the VM will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i has error in log which is located:

```
"C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log"
```

My error:

> PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

[This answer helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60525814/15799562)

Answer (score 1):

Really, I had same issue. I had tried over 10 times..im not professor but I found finally. It was a tough time for me.

Try again follow next.

If you install Android again again, I think import setting has problem. wrong Path on android screen. not environment Path
Because automatically it is determined old path(when it installed first)

and Choose a lower API if possible
in my case, when I use API 17, the emulator acted. but API 30, The emulator has terminated...so, I think if you use windows 7 or low spec, use low API environment.
In addition, I needed installing emulator-windows_x64-7491168,zip (In my case)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After having tested solutions suggested in this forum, the only one which solved the problem to me is to free space in my hard disk. In my case I needed at least 7 GB to make it work.

Comment: I had 6GB free, After clearing another 4GB, I was able to run the emulator

Answer (score 1):

[image]In my case, lowering the API version to 28 for System Image x86 helped when creating new Virtual Device.

Answer (score 1):

I select configuration of the emulator graphics "Hardware-GLES 2.0", it worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i had tried all the above solution but couldn't succeed.
finally i have got rid of this issue in my HP PC by uninstalling the pre installed program **hp wolf security**.

Comment: This is working. After I uninstall all the HP related softwares from the machine, the Emulator started working. None of the other solutions worked for me Except this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open "Edit this AVD".
2. In the section "Emulator Performance" change Graphic type to another (for example, Software - GLES 1.1).

I have an old video card and this is work in my case.

Comment: the dropdown list is disabled, I cannot change to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If emulator is terminating and it was properly running earlier and even if you have enough disk space. You can delete and create a new Virtual device which is almost same as "Wipe Data" action on existing Emulator. But if you do not want to wipe data and loose any kind of progress made on the Emulator, There is a "Cold Boot" option for you which helps. It actually solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open device manager
2. Click menu
3. run cold boot

Answer (score 1):

I removed one previous emulator and then run the new one it worked for me :)

Comment: This was the same issue I had, I had two different .android locations with avd. deleted the old one and the issue resolved by itself

Answer (score 1):

As this issue took me quite some time to resolve, I want to share my solution on OSX as well. To be honest, in my case the problem was that I had previously used the Android SDK without Android Studio and thus an environment variable was not configured correctly.

Checking the `idea.log` (Help > Show Log in Finder) I realized those error details:

```
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define  ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

I quickly added the environment variable to my `.zshrc` (Prefernces > ... > Android SDK), in my case:

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/felixgeissler/Library/Android/sdk
```

But to this point the problem persisted:

```
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/Users/felixgeissler/Library/Android/sdk]!
```

After that I realized that I had defined the `ANDROID_HOME` variable in my `.zshrc` as well. **Removing this entry somehow resolved issue!** I assume that the removed variable interfered with the SDK root.

Comment: This blog post pointed me in the right direction:
https://betamode.de/2018/11/16/android-emulator-panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android_sdk_root-value/

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to disable emulator VM acceleration.

You can force the use of the soft x86 emulator by running it from the command line and using the -no-accel option.

i.e. from the SDK/tools directory on Windows :

To list available AVDs:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -list-avds
```

To disable VM acceleration:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_4_API_29 -no-accel -no-boot-anim
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#common

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you had ANDROID_SDK_ROOT with a valid SDK path in your system environment.
that happens when you move your SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I upgraded the Emulator, the solution that worked for me is:
-updating windows
-and remove all the AVDs then I installed a new one.(release name:Pie,

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by clearing data of the emulator, and then restart the emulator. Finally the emulator has not terminate when launched

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of latest Emulator .

I upgraded to v30.6.4 last night and got the same issue.

Team fixed issue and released new version do update it ,
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXYJs.png**

well its working now

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the Android Emulator and reinstall it.
Also I freed up some space to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

For me unchecking the "Multi-Core CPU" option in the virtual device configuration did the job. It is listed under "Advanced Settings".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. From the logs, the error code pointed to a lack of space for creating userdata. So, deleting caches of previously deleted VDs did the job for me. Go to C:\Users\user.android\avd and delete any unused files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when I tried to start a second Virtual Device (VD).  I was able to resolve the issue by, simply, closing the currently running VD.  Once I did this, I was able to run multiple VDs.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I solved this issue.
I created an AVD with API 28 [ Non google play version] .
Choose x86 64 version.
Increase the RAM size of AVD to 2 GB
Choose Graphic - Hardware GLES 2.0

with this i could able to launch the the AVD and it is much faster than previous one

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I had a mismatch in my $ANDROID_HOME envvar.

It was pointed to an old location before I had downloaded Android Studio. Updated to `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` and we are good.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the solution was executing the VulkanRT-Installer.exe

Answer (score 0):

android studio has issue with special characters where the issue could be due to the mapping where the emulator runs. I had this problem where I was running on my `C:/User` that had 'ã' and with that the same error occurred.
To fix change the Windows environment variable '`ANDROID_USER_HOME`' to a folder with a common name for example `C:\Android\sdk`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, running Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Issue in my case was a mismatch between NVideo kernel module and NVideo client libraries, as noted from `dmesg` output (these log entries appeared each time an AVD was restarted and failed):

```
NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version 470.103.01, but
NVRM: this kernel module has the version 470.86.  Please                           
NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver                           
NVRM: components have the same version.
```

Solution in my case was to upgrade the NVidia drivers to package nvidia-driver-510 using the `Additional Drivers` dialog of Ubuntu.  Then reboot.

Answer (score 0):

change the "Graphics" property in the AVD,choose "Soft ware --Gles2.0".
it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Short story long

I came into this issue two weeks ago on Windows 11. I haven't performed anything special with my setup over the weekend. But on Monday I could not run emulator. I tried Updating/Reinstalling Android Studio and it's modules via SDK manager. Nothing helped.

In **C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\log\idea.log** I found some issues with Vulkan during emulator starting.

## What helped

Updating Windows and Nvidia drivers to latest version.
@Darren Smith fixed this issue for Ubuntu by updating Nvidia drivers too. If it won't help you can at least enjoy latest bugs for your hardware...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating Android Emulator and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) version in Android Studio. Both these components were outdated after update of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem happened on a MacBook Pro with an Apple silicon CPU (m1, arm64), because I've migrated the Android Studio and Android SDK from an older MacBook Pro with Intel CPU. I've re-installed the ARM version of Android Studio then and updated the Android SDK, but seems that Intel emulator version persisted. The solution was just uninstall and reinstall the Android Emulator:

Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools tab

Answer (score 0):

**Go to Task Manager using (Ctrl+Alt+Delete) and check in background processes that emulator is not running in background. If it is running in background, end task and try to start your emulator again.**

Answer (score 0):

goto avd folder

delete all avd's

and relaunch avd

hope you will find avd working fine

Answer (score 0):

I selected a system image from `ARM Images` instead of  `Other Images` and the emulator is running fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Everything Fine. Good Work. Just make a little change. If you have 2 different pixel types appearing on Virtual Device section you have to delete any one of the pixel emulator which you do not prefer for your project. Delete it by clicking drop down arrow > Delete. It'll work for you the way it did for me. If you already have 1 pixel emulator, I might be wrong in telling you that the problem is you need SUFFICIENT SPACE where your ADVs generated OR you need to upgrade the HAXM installer to the latest --v

Comment: This answer just refers to the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68682990/1387386

Comment: Thanks for telling. I did not see it when creating solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be due to different reasons; in my case it was due to the path not found to the system-images folder. Somehow my system-images folder inside sdk was missing. Since I had a backup of my sdk, I put the old one into sdk folder and the emulator started to work. If you are seeing something like below in the log file, try this approach.

Emulator: Pixel 2 API 28 - emulator: WARN: path_getAvdSystemPath: ..rootdirectory/Android/sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis_playstore/x86/ is not a valid directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open the directory in which os is installed. Then Users > <YOUR_USERNAME> >.android/avd/<AVD_NAME>.avd/

Delete all files ending .lock extension

Answer (score 0):

Because i didn't see my solution for this problem yet:

In my case it was a problem with the environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. I have installed 2 different ANDROID SDKs and the problem was that my environment variable targeted another SDK than my Android Studio SDK Manager.

Turns out you have to set the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to the same Android-SDK-Path as Android Studio (`Android Studio -> SDK Manager`) points to.

I found this solution in the android studio logs. See [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622341/19886928).

Answer (score 0):

1. I **deleted** the **emulator** folder: ~/Android/Sdk/emulator
2. Then I opened Android Studio, opened Android SDK Tools: Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools
3. I **checked the box for Android Emulator** then I clicked **Apply**

Answer (score 0):

This might sound dumb but...

I'm new to Android Studio, and I tried all the tricks listed above with over 100Gb free space. I constantly got the dreaded 'Emulator has been terminated message' every time I tried to create a virtual device.  In the same time I also installed on MacOs and I did not have the least issue.

I accidentally stumbled on something solved the issue for me.  Since I couldn't create a virtual device, I physically connected my phone via USB. After this I did my first build and during the build I got an error saying that the path to the Android SDK is not writable.  For some reason my PATH variable for Android SDK was set to the Program Files directory in Windows.  I changed this to the actual location which is c:\users\myuserid\appdata\local\Android\Sdk.

Now my build worked and afterwards I found I could create AVD easily! Phew.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have Windows Media Pack installed, this is required to run emulator, it's not documented and not may users notice, I have Windows 11 Enterprise N which is the N variant that does come without Media Pack and emulator didn't work until I installed it.

Apps > Optional Features > Add feature > Windows Media Pack

Please post the system type and version from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with kill adb and start again it:

go to adb.exe in => C:\Users\simab-lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Android\Sdk\platform-tools , and start cmd and write below command
adb kill-server
adb start-server

Answer (score 0):

I tryied all possiblilities,Just Make 6-7 gb space on drive worked for me.If you don't have enough space on disk might cause this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete other unused devices which are using disk space and free them up.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by wiping the user data of emulator. Simply go to Device Manager then click on the device menu and Wipe Data, and then again run the app on that emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Lake of disk space in my hard drive was the root cause. Make sure that the amount of free space in your hard drive is greater than the amount of internal storage of your Virtual Device.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting#disk-space

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the methods described here, but it did not help to fix the error.

I installed the emulator manually.
I used the emulator from the official resource [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive).

I chose an emulator with a date that roughly corresponded to the version of Android Studio. I did everything as written in the instructions.

My Android Studio 2022.1.1

Chose Emulator 32.1.12

For example video [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr1MKRTMeP8&t=0s)

Answer (score 0):

Win7 x64 + Android Studio 2023.1: killing process tree for `qemu-system` helped.
This one left in the process list even after IDE closed.

Answer (score -1):

I just restarted my machine and it worked.
And yea! I agree with anatolii-shuba’s answer with the main cause been as a result of lack of free space on your disk

Comment: Please don't add "I agree with" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer.