# Android studio Arctic Fox beta 3 on M1 Chip (Apple silicon) emulator cannot start: "The emulator process for AVD 'myAvdName' has terminated."

Tags: android, qt, emulation, apple-m1

Have Android studio both official latest and Arctic Fox Beta 3 installed on my MacBook Air M1. cannot get the emulator running on neither edition of android stood.

> "The emulator process for AVD 'myavxname' has terminated."

I have made sure I use the other (ARM image) instead of the Intel ones, as there are quite some posts on the web and it seems those post saved many, not me.

I use the command in terminal to check more helpful error message:

> ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator -avd P4S

, p4s is my emulator config name.

also run the command

> pip3 install opencv-python-headless

still blocked by this error below.

> emulator: Android emulator version 30.3.5.0 (build_id 7036990)
> (CL:N/A) emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
> handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf emulator: INFO:
> QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: Could not find the Qt platform plugin
> "cocoa" in
> "/Users//Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins"
> ((null):0, (null))
>
> Fatal: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin
> could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this
> problem.  ((null):0, (null)) emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Fatal:
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
> ((null):0, (null))

and here is the ls-lR > ls.txt of my folder under Android/sdk/emulator/lib64

> total 0 drwxr-xr-x  9   staff  288 Jun 12 15:44 lib
> drwxr-xr-x  3   staff   96 Jun 12 15:44 libexec
> -rw-r--r--  1   staff    0 Jun 14 23:59 ls.txt drwxr-xr-x  7   staff  224 Jun 12 15:35 plugins drwxr-xr-x  2 
> staff   64 Jun 12 15:44 resources drwxr-xr-x  3   staff   96
> Jun 12 15:35 translations
>
> ./lib: total 52872
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff  7833392 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5CoreAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff   899808 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5DBusAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff  7123104 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5GuiAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff  2180144 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5NetworkAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff   466768 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5PrintSupportAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff   477808 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5SvgAndroidEmu.5.dylib
> -rwxr-xr-x  1   staff  8073344 Jun 12 15:44 libQt5WidgetsAndroidEmu.5.dylib
>
> ./libexec: total 0 drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:44
> qtwebengine_locales
>
> ./libexec/qtwebengine_locales:
>
> ./plugins: total 0 drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:45
> bearer drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:45 iconengines
> drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:45 imageformats
> drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:45 platforms drwxr-xr-x
> 2   staff  64 Jun 12 15:45 styles
>
> ./plugins/bearer:
>
> ./plugins/iconengines:
>
> ./plugins/imageformats:
>
> ./plugins/platforms:
>
> ./plugins/styles:
>
> ./resources:
>
> ./translations: total 0 drwxr-xr-x  2   staff  64 Jun 12
> 15:44 qtwebengine_locales
>
> ./translations/qtwebengine_locales:

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the emulator.
You can try:

- downgrading your emulator (answer by @igor-levkivskiy)
- using another emulator (amswer by @bhw1899)
- changing the advanced settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEaJ.png (answer by @julio)

Source:
[Android Emulator Issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67346232)

Comment: Where are the advanced Settings ?

Comment: @WaqasTahir VDM -> Device -> Actions (right) -> Dropdown-Menu -> Edit  -> Show Advanced Settings

Comment: Hey , I can't downgrade my emulator , I can't find the link to previous version !
Could you please help me , if you could give me the link to previous version , I updated to latest version and now it does not work and changing advanced settings did not work as well !

Comment: @WaqasTahir Just create another virtual device, e.g. Pixel5.

Comment: All the virtual devices are giving this error !

Answer (score 1):

Had same error. Resolved by [100% uninstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac) Android Studio. Not sure which files specifically were culprit. Removed all of them per post. I also changed directory to root file system `/` and searched for Android related files and removed those as well  `find . -name "*android*" > ~/Desktop/files.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, I Installed the canary edition of Android Studio (see specs below). Also I could only install and run Arm images based on Android SDK version S.

```
(Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 3
Build #AI-211.7442.40.2111.7518594, built on July 2, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
```