# Android Studio Flutter - WARNING: Another emulator is still running - windows 10

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am having problems restarting the emulator after turning it off. Restarting android studio - doesn't help. Restarting my computer helps.
I also cannot find and [stop this process] through the task manager. So that I can not reboot.
By the way, the error is displayed with a typo.
Help. Who faced such a problem, how to solve it?

```
emulator: WARNING: Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... emulator: WARNING: 
Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... emulator: WARNING: Another emualtor is 
still running, wait for a sec... emulator: ERROR: Another emulator instance is running. 
Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag. emulator: Android emulator version
30.6.5.0 (build_id 7324830) (CL:N/A)
```

[Another emualtor is still running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8uKo.png)

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale ru-UA)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (4 days ago), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ArtRyzen\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[√] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at C:\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • android-studio-dir = C:\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.101
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 91.0.864.48
```

> **The problem was solved by reinstalling the emulator.**

Comment: Hi,are you trying to run multiple emulators at once?

Comment: I'd suggest go to device manager, wipe the data and try again. If it works then great,  if you still get the error then delete the emulator(s) and add a new one

Comment: I only ran one emulator at the same time. The wipe of the device did not help either. In general, the problem was solved in the most obvious way :) I deleted the old emulator, rebooted the computer, installed a new one, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

On Windows, the software that runs the Android Emulator is called "qemu-system-x86_64.exe".

Try to *kill* this software.

You can use the Windows Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) or the  built-in [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) utility from within the Command Prompt:

1. Open the Command Prompt (Type in CMD into the Windows Search)
2. Enter: `taskkill /F /IM "qemu-system-x86_64.exe" /T`

---

Explanation of the [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)  command:

```
/F    Specifies that processes be forcefully ended. This parameter is ignored for remote processes; all remote processes are forcefully ended.

/T    Ends the specified process and any child processes started by it.

/IM   Specifies the image name of the process to be terminated.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It would be more correct to try your solution firs. But the problem has already been resolved. Now I will wait for the next bug with the emulator. With these frequent constant flutter updates, they come up quite often :)

Comment: @Artem Ha! The problem _might_ be something else. If it happens again, please update in the comments of this answer if this solution has worked.

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. This is my first post. So I'll keep an eye on it :)

Comment: Windows Task Manager, kill qemu-system-x86_64.exe

Comment: In `Visual Studio 22` and `Windows 11`, the `qemu-system-x86_64.exe` process is nested inside the VS22 task group.

Comment: Hi @Artem, can I ask you how did you solve this issue? I'm running into the same issue myself and taskkill, restarting the PC and reinstalling Android SDK didn't do much for me :(

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS and Linux:

```
rm ~/.android/avd/Pixel_4_XL_API_33.avd/*.lock
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on Windows) I needed to kill the "Android Emulator - ..." process
From task manager
[image]