# This Error Came In Every time I Open Android studio emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Every time I try to open the emulator in the Android studio this error comes in

> INFO | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A) INFO | Found systemPath D:\Softwares\Android Things\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\ ERROR | Failed to retrieve DNS servers list from the system WARNING | Cannot find system DNS servers! Name resolution will be disabled. ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD ERROR | is an experimental feature. ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature. INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\SASMIT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.

I did everything to fix this like,
changing the emulator, and reinstalling the software but any of them didn't work.

please!!! help me with this, if you know how

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67987153/android-studio-flutter-warning-another-emulator-is-still-running-windows-10/67987770#67987770


and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297335/cannot-run-flutter-app-on-android-virtual-device

Answer (score -1):

some additional steps you can try:

Change the graphics option from Auto to Software-GLES2. This can sometimes fix the issue if the emulator is having trouble rendering graphics.

Try solving it by selecting "Use Host GPU" as the emulation option at the bottom of the "Create..." screen. This will use your computer's GPU to render graphics, which can sometimes improve performance.

Wipe the data of that emulator. This will delete all of the emulator's settings and data, which can sometimes fix problems.