# The emulator process for avd has terminated

Tags: android-studio, crash, android-emulator, expo

Have problem with launching emulator of Android via Android Studio.

When I tried to do it - I got next warning message:

> The emulator process for avd has terminated.

I checked log and main expression was:

> Broken AVD system path.
> Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Users\User.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_30.avd\Pixel_XL_API_30.avd]!

(I tried to change path many times, so don't pay attention to it)

When I tried to launch emulator from folder - I got crash report "qt5core android emu dll doesn't exist" and more other related dll. (HAEX installed, Android Studio latest version, Default Androids SDK is in **disk D**). All folders (platform-tools and other) are not corrupted .

[Terminated process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoXCu.png)

[Disk D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tBEe.png)

[Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5ICF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may turn off vulkan by adding this file to your User(your user).android

(if not exist), till google solve the bug about Vulkan.

the file: advancedFeatures.ini

Contents:

```
    BluetoothEmulation = on
    GrallocSync = on
    GLDMA = on
    LogcatPipe = on
    GLAsyncSwap = on
    GLESDynamicVersion = on
    EncryptUserData = on
    VirtioWifi = on
    HostComposition = on
    RefCountPipe = on
    VirtioInput = on
    HardwareDecoder = on
    DynamicPartition = on
    ModemSimulator= on
    MultiDisplay = on
    YUVCache = on
    GLDirectMem = on
    Vulkan = off
    VulkanNullOptionalStrings = on
    VulkanIgnoredHandles = on
    Mac80211hwsimUserspaceManaged = on
    VirtconsoleLogcat = on
    VirtioVsockPipe = on
    AndroidbootProps2 = on
    DeviceSkinOverlay = on
    VulkanQueueSubmitWithCommands = on
    VulkanBatchedDescriptorSetUpdate = on
    DeviceStateOnBoot = on
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution for beginners: Have suffient space on your HD... !
You need more than the default 2GB.
I had so far not reached my first code line in Android due to the problem "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 has terminated problem.
Assement of relevant info:
Win10 on HP Compact 8200 (from the Win7 period.)
With 10G of 100G remaining on actual SSD.

Based on similar advice under Mac/OS I) deleted ...API29 and tried Galaxy NexusAPI22 and got my first emulated phone on the screen and with 2.7GB remaining.

Answer (score 2):

I tried each and every step mentioned in stackoverflow but for me reinstalling the graphic card driver solve the issue. AVD is now working.
Please try reinstalling a graphic driver.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the device mirroring settings and enable the option turn off device display while mirroring:

[image: Screenshot of settings pane]