# Android AVD - The emulator process for AVD <emulator_name> has terminated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I searched here on StackOverflow and found many similar questions with many different answers, but none of them worked for me.

So,I was using the emulators from Android Studio very well on the last days until I tried to add a new Virtual Device with *Google Play API*, When I tried to run it this message appeared:

> The emulator process for AVD <emulator_name> has terminated.

I tried many different things and also removed all emulators I had, but now not a single one that I create works

Here is the log I get in the Android Studio logs:

```txt
[1647414]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\2DWeb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapstorage -avd cel_30_debug1 
[1649364]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. 
[1649364]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release. 
[1649380]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: WARNING | Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only. 
[1650143]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: C:\Users\2DWeb\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe:/qemu.conf:1: no group defined 
[1651630]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz 
[1651630]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll 
[1651665]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.1.4.0 (build_id 7920983) (CL:N/A) 
[1651665]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I even unninstalled Android Studio and deleted all related directories and installed it all again, didn't work.

Some important things:

- Tried With or without Google Play API or Google APIs
- Tried different SDK APIs (8.1 [*API 27*], 10 [*API 29*], 11 [*API 30*]...)
- I have free space on HD: about 40gb
- The emulator is setted to 16gb of internal storage
- I tried x86 and x86_64 architecture (both was working two days ago)
- Tried Quick Boot and Cold Boot
- Tried to add a new emulator and don't change anything on the specs (using default)
- The Android Emulator on SDK Tools is updated to latest version (31.1.4)
- Installed the latest HAXM version (7.7.0)
- I have an Intel processor (and as far as I know, no changes were made on it) and 12gb RAM

None of the above made the emulators work.

Comment: Hi, are you sure your CPU supports intel vtd-vtx ? Is it on?
Have you tried to turn it on using cold boot?

Comment: As you can read in the list of things I tried, in my question. I tried cold boot. Also, i didn't made any changes to my CPU, and last week it was wroking normally

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Comment: Do you have Windows Media Pack installed? on N variants of windows it's not installed by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work...

Apparently, the Android Emulator updated to the latest version was the problem. Apparently many conflicts with vulkan.dll and other emulation process stopped working with this new version (at least for me in my computer).

I downloaded an old version of the android emulator based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64154443/8691276) and then it started working again...

Answer (score 13):

Go to your android studio, select “Tools” ->” SDK Manager” -> “SDK Tools” tab -> and update to the latest Android Emulator version. Then rerun your emulator again. Solved! Hope it helps.

Comment: To which version of emulator, because as you could read from my question, I did that and it was exactly what caused the problem...

Comment: this worked for me. I updated the sdk tools too to the latest version

Comment: Yes, that worked. "Help" > "Check for updates" -- then install updates, restart was all it took.

Answer (score 5):

**As of May 2020, for Macbook M1 (Pro/Max) users who still struggle**....

First, do not launch the emulator from Android Studio. It provides no information other than the unuseful **"AVD has been killed or terminated"** message.

Instead, type this.

```bash
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

it returns a more detailed message like below.

```bash
emulator: ERROR: process is translated under Rosetta. Attempting to replace emulator installation.
emulator: Replacing via command: /Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/darwin-aarch64-replace.sh (downloading ~120 MB)...
sh: /Users/<USER>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/darwin-aarch64-replace.sh: No such file or directory
emulator: Replacement done. Please relaunch the emulator. You will also need to be using an Apple Silicon-compatible system image. Check the release updates blog (https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/) for more details
```

So in my case **darwin-aarch64-replace.sh** is missing!

Download [the file from here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/android-emulator/+/ed4d8fc6e2d9c8f97c667a78ed5c0675cb633e11/darwin-x86_64/darwin-aarch64-replace.sh).

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, I had to uninstall **NDK (side by side)** using the **SDK Manager**

Comment: With NDK we need to install the C make for it to work https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions make sure the **Disk space** is available on your machine. An Emulator requires lots of disk space as it a system on its own.

Comment: I had to end up just using my own phone as the device for running it and I suspect this is why.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when running my react native app, I manually installed NDK from the  SDK manager.

With NDK we need to install the C make for it to work, this is how I solved this issue.

Read the docs for more info.

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk

Answer (score 0):

Open the Task Manager and kill the process "qemu-system"

Comment: unrelated to the question

Answer (score 0):

New Solution i had found for this  Go to help and delete Left over IDE Directory and delete all Directory
then restart android studio and AVD
Its working...
Happy Coding

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My case: Fixed this problem several times by Kumudika Jayantha's answer above.

But it does not work any more. You can use OmniDeskSweeper app on Mac to delete all Android caches and folders, then re-install Android studio. (Make sure delete all the old Android studio files and download new Android studio app from official site, 2 hours on this problem).

Another case: You can use OmniDeskSweeper to find and delete all *.lock files.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After having tried many things, the only one that worked for me was the following: enter Device Mirroring Settings and enable the option, "Turn off device display while mirroring." After that, it is important that you first initialize it from Device Manager.

[image]

Comment: Please do not [post duplicated answers to multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77555522/5211833). Instead, answer the best one you can find and, once you reach [15 reputation](/help/privileges/flag-posts), flag the other question as a [duplicate](/help/duplicates), associating the questions with each other and thus keeping knowledge centralised.