# Android Studio Emulator gets terminated when running

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

every time I try running my emulator for my Virutal Device, the device gets terminated. I tried installing another emulator with the AMD stuff but I'm running into different problems there. I'm new to flutter so it would be great if someone can help me fixing this problem.[image]

Comment: Check your Task manager for any running instances of emulator like `emulator.exe` or `qemu-X-X.exe`. Ending them may solve the problem.

Comment: there isnt something like that, I also tried restarting my pc several times. I'm sitting at this since 7 hours I also tried reinstalling the emulators or changing the devices and the Android Versions. Nothing helps.

Comment: Lack of free space might also cause the problem. Take a look at answers to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/67346232/10086742

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Comment: yeah I already saw that thinking it isnt the problem because my folder are in my D: but Android Studio needed the space from C: so now I moved the important things to D: and it works.