# How can i fix The emulator process for avd xxx has terminated error

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, mobile, android-emulator

I tried all things for fix avd terminated error but still stuck and cant open emulator.
[image]

What I tried :

- Reinstall android studio. SDK. Flutter.
- Added system variables.
- Opened Hyper-V on windows features.
- Choose under API 30 while creating new emulator.

How can i fix it ?
My System variables :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I really search a lot and cant fix it anyway. Please help thanks for helps <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Answer (score 4):

1. [Try to repeat as in this video.](https://youtu.be/bOURCXjmXlg)
2. Look at the amount of free space on this disk, it should be more than 10 gigabytes, more is better.
3. 

> Faced this issue after update to arctic fox.
>
> After seeing error message about termination, open android studio logs
>
> ("C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log")
>
> scroll it down and try to find log line with text "Emulator terminated
> with exit code". Probably, the reason for termination can be found a
> few lines above this message - for me it was
>
> "Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed".
>
> If you have the same reason - go to C:\Windows\System32 directory,
> search here for file called vulkan-1-999-0-0-0.dll and just rename it
> to vulkan-1.dll (i've made a copy just in case and named it
> "vulkan-1.dll").

4. Try changing your emulator settings, the amount of memory and processor cores used.
5. 

> Open text editor (eg. notepad) Type this code: Vulkan=off
> GLDirectMem=on Save the file as "advancedFeatures.ini" in .android
> directory. If your user is named Admin, under windows it would be:
> C:\Users\Admin.android\advancedFeatures.ini.
>
> Run your app.

[Original link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the option for graphics rendering to 'Software' instead of 'Automatic' or 'Hardware'. It solved the problem for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated).

The answer read:

1. Open android studio logs

("C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\log\idea.log")

2. scroll it down and try to find log line with text "Emulator terminated with exit code".

The reason for termination can be found a few lines above this message - for me it was it a lack of disk space (it needs 7gb and I had 4b), for the user that wrote this it was "Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed", and you can check out the link to see what they did about it.

But by going to the log file you can diagnose the issue, instead of the 101 different answers you see when searching it!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed my windows 11 system as windows PRO N.
But windows PRO N means the windows system that does not supports media feature.
So, the system didn't support media feature and it was why the error was happened.
After installing PRO, It works correctly.
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use **Android 8.1 Oreo** version. Apparently modern android versions can run on modern hardware (my pc is powerful but old).

I can't add images, but I can include a link:

[See images](https://images.jonathanhernandez.click/)

I hope I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case and after a clean install or upgrade of Android Studio, Pixel 3 API 31 emulator would work for a few days and then crash every time I tried to load it - I typically run the emulator from VSCode but when it starts to crash, it does so in both AS and VSC.
I then started using Pixel 3 API 30 and, again, this would work for a few days and then crash every time.

What fixed it for me was simply increasing the 'Internal Storage' setting from its default of 6GB to 20GB in the AS AVD manager for each of the problem emulators - see screenshot below.

BTW, my environment is Win 11 Insider Preview PC, i7 Gen 11 CPU, 64GB ram, couple of TBs of disk space free on the drive where it runs.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRDt8.png)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was space. Try to at least have a minimum of 7GB free