# Android SDK no log for Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, event-log, android-sdk-manager

I want to create my first application in Android SDK.

But when I want to start the emulator, I have this error message : "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_5_API_15 has terminated."

I tried few android phones version but I have always the same issue : "The emulator process for [...] has terminated."

But the real probleme is : I have no logs !!

In the "Event log" window, there is any message from the emulator process.

I was looking in the settings of the event log, but the Android Emulator is enabled in the notifications.

So I don't know what's my problem ...

How can I see the log of my emulator ?

Thanks !

**EDIT :**

Thanks Adinia, with your link, I find the log, and here is what I get :

```
2022-04-25 14:25:51,315 [1658570]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: E:\Android_SDK\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_15 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-04-25 14:25:51,614 [1658869]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT 
2022-04-25 14:25:51,614 [1658869]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-04-25 14:25:51,614 [1658869]   INFO - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1 
2022-04-25 14:25:51,614 [1658869]   WARN - manager.EmulatorProcessHandler - Emulator terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

Comment: Also, logs for your application will be in the Logcat tab, not the Event log one. But so far doesn't seem to be a problem with your application, but with your emulator.

Comment: I have no log in the Logcat tab too.

Comment: That's entirely normal: since the emulator is not booting, it's not possible to install the app, so no logs yet. Focus on fixing your emulator first or use a physical device.

Comment: Yes, but I need log to know how to fix the emulator