# The emulator process for AVD has terminated (Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, appium, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

[image]

I tried as in python . But the emulator has terminated .

Comment: Have you checked [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try shifting to a previous version i also got this error and going back and using a stable version helped!

Comment: This is not a proper solution.