# Android studio - emulator process for AVD has terminated - windows 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-11, android-studio-electric-eel

“The emulator process for AVD has terminated” - I am getting this error

I am using windows 11 home
Android studio version is electric Eel 2022.1.1

I installed hyper-v and virtualizations are enabled in bios setup
I have more than 150gb space in disk as well

Even though I am not able to install
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(Haxm installer) in SDK tools - In the beginning Emulator worked then after sometime it got terminated

I tried reinstalling the whole android studio - again emulator worked for some time then it got terminated

Answer (score 2):

Install Media Feature Pack on Windows.
[image]

Comment: We can't see an error in `idea.log` for this. But if we launch the avd manually, then we can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71765657/2348614
Then I saw error for some missing dll, which I acquired when I installed this `Media Feature Pack`.

Answer (score 1):

[Perhaps this could be your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68917350/19610655)

1. Go to Tools -> SDK Manager [SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC597.png)
2. In SDK Manager Go To SDK Tools Tab and untick the Android Emulator and click on Apply. This step will uninstall the Android Emulator. [Uninstalling Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7b6t.png)
3. After uninstallation completes: Again Open Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools -> Install the Android Emulator by enabling the check or tick on Android Emulator. This step will install the Android Emulator again.
4. After successful installation. Restart Android Studio. Create new emulator device and Run it. This should work. [(Source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68917350/19610655)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your computer storage capacity. The emulator uses a partition your system memory and storage when it wants to run (that way the running memory is freed up when the emulator is not running) and so if your device memory or storage is significantly low, it will not be able to run.

I encountered that issue a number of times and freeing my computer storage space resolved it for me.

Answer (score -2):

just create a new device in Device Manager, I dont know why this issue happen.It seems it is about the new version of Android Studio.