# Unable to launch emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm running mac os mojave (intel chip) and installed android studio flamingo (latest stable).  After creating a new emulator I try to run an app and see "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_28 has terminated."  A similar thread [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated/70648740) was posted but my laptop is not running out of storage as the solution says.

installed android studio and expected the bundled emulator to start.

Answer (score 2):

bundled emulator has issues with mac OS older versions.

You can confirm the same with idea logs ( Android Studio -> Help -> Show log in finder)
open the **idea.log** in any editor and check the root cause of emulator crash.

in my case :

I observed something like **which was built for Mac OS X 11.1** ,
but my Mac OS version is **10.13.6**

So downgraded the emulator to older version **31.3.14** , now am able to launch the emulator.

**How to downgrade the emulator version** , in detail steps with older versions of emulators can be seen here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive

Answer (score -1):

The problem was using a newer version of android studio than my OS would allow.  You can fix this by downgrading AS or upgrading mac os.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).