# "Android Emulator has terminated" I got this error in every time when I create a new virtual device in my Android Studio?

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

The error that I got every time from new android emulator that I created,

[image]

For your information :

Here is the flutter doctor,

[image]

I also add the android sdk path,

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing to add or to update? Please suggest me because I'm stucked here from 1 week?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because there is not enough space on the disk. Can you try these steps?

1. Android Virtual Device(AVD) -> Show Advanced Settings
   [image]
2. Change these:

   Graphics: Software

   Ram: 512

[image]

Also the answers here may help:
[Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.

Answer (score 0):

got mine working by setting ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in my environment variables. You can always check your logs if it doesn't help, that's where I found out where I was getting this error from. Good luck