# How do i fix emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Every time i try to run a program i get this message. (Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5EB9.png)

I tried to free some space in my disk and right now i have 4GB free space but this didnt fix the issue. Im not sure what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: I think your question needs a little more context. The information provided could mean any error occurred and we would need to know more to figure out the cause of the error you're having.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this POST, this might be similar to what you are experiencing, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.