# Cannot start Android emulator

Tags: c#, android, android-emulator, maui

Windows 10, Ryzen 5 1600, MSI B450 Tomahawk Max.
Visual Studio Preview Community, .NET MAUI project.
Emulator pixel_5_-_api_34 cannot be started.
When I try to start emulator from Android Device Manager I get 'could not start emulator using host gpu mode' 'Please check if you can update your video driver.
If it doesn't help, try to Edit the AVD and set "hw.gpu.mode=off"'.

Also cannot start emulator from Android Studio. I get next error:
Failed to install the following SDK components:
build-tools;33.0.1 Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1
Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
When I try run emulator from Device Manager I get next error:
The emulator process for AVD has terminated.

Also cannot start emulator from Delphi XE5.

I checked Windows Hyper-V. I set hw.gpu.mode=off.
I added the code below in advancedFeatures.ini.
`WindowsHypervisorPlatform=on Vulkan = off GLDirectMem = on`

Nothing helped. Please help.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still cannot run the emulator from VS22 but can run Genymotion emulator.
Choose Run -> Android Local Devices -> The Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

For Windows 11, I install Visual Studio Preview Community and create Emulator pixel_5_-_api_34 to run MAUI project. It works well.

So you can try to use VS instead of VS Preview. Or use Windows 11.

**Solution 2**

Update the Android Emulator component(`Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager`) and set GPU mode to `auto`. For more operational details, please refer to this thread: [Android Emulator HW GPU Accelaration destroyed after latest Windows Update](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/android-emulator-hw-gpu-accelaration-destroyed-aft/1668072).

In addition, about the error: The emulator process for AVD has terminated, you check this case: [Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated).

Hope these can help you!