# Android studio - " The emulator process for AVD has terminated"

Tags: android-studio

C:\Users\21508\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-33.1.24.db\attachments\1a176ff8-369d-47ad-90e4-806d75040094: The system cannot find the file specified.

ive deleted and reinstalled the app, wiped data from AVD, cold booted... still not working.

enough disk space available. using windows 10

Comment: Can you provide more precise logs to your problem please ? See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622341/11239251 Note tthat other answers may be usefull to your question