# Android emulator not working after Studio upgrade

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Just upgraded from Android Studio 4.1 to ArcticFox 2020.3.1.

Emulator was working fine in 4.1 but now nothing shows. Sometimes the status line says 'waiting for emulator to start...' for a few seconds, but otherwise nothing, no error messages.
As part of the upgrade, it recommended to use the HAXM accelerator which I installed.
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100167/android-emulators-not-working-after-updating-android-studio) thread but it hasn't helped (it refers to a much older version of Studio).
The app runs OK on a  real device.

I have tried adding a new (different) virtual device; same problem. I also have the same problem on two upgraded PCs (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in these two threads:

[emulator process terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated)

[cannot find vulkan-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65696048/android-studio-emulator-cannot-add-library-vulkan-1-dll-failed)

But puzzled why these weren't offered as solutions when I added my question.